# real-time output of process in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process

I have the following class for diskparting and imaging a pc.  The form has a regular text box (tb1) that lists each step of the process (output) and a rich text box (rtb1) that outputs real time process info.  The problem I'm having is the app isn't waiting for the real time output to finish before starting the next sub routine.  See attached code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Private Property pcSerial As Object = GetBiosSerialNumber()
Private Property title As String = "Ross PC Imaging"
Private Property pcModel As Object
Private Property wkstn As String
Private Property srvr As Object

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Call ross()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call ross()
End Sub

Private Sub ross()
    Dim objCS As ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim objMgmt As ManagementObject
    objCS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objMgmt In objCS.Get
        pcModel = objMgmt("model").ToString()
    Next

    Output(pcModel)
    Output(pcSerial)

    'Map network drive
    Call MapDrive()

    'Diskpart
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " physical drives being partitioned and formatted")
    If pcModel = "Server" Then
        Call diskpart("srvr")
    Else
        Call diskpart("wkstn")
    End If
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " physical drives have been partitioned and formatted")
    Dim msgDiskPart As String : msgDiskPart = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " physical drives partitioned and formatted")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDiskPart)

    'Dism
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " imaging started")
    If pcModel = "Server" Then
        Call dism("srvr")
    Else
        Call dism("wkstn")
    End If
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " imaging completed")
    Dim msgImgStop As String : msgImgStop = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - " & pcSerial & " imaged")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgImgStop)

    'Reboot
    'Call reboot()
End Sub

Private Sub MapDrive()
    'Map network drive
    Dim map As New Process()
    map.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe"
    map.StartInfo.Arguments = " use t: \\172.47.3.254\wims"
    map.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    map.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    map.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    map.Start()
    map.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub diskpart(ByVal pctype As String)
    'Diskpart disk partitioning
    Dim dp As New Process()
    dp.StartInfo.FileName = "diskpart.exe"
    dp.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s x:\" & pctype & "_diskpart.txt"
    dp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dp.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dp.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dp.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dp.Start()
    dp.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dp.BeginOutputReadLine()
End Sub

Private Sub dism(ByVal imgFile As String)
    'Image C Drive
    Dim dismC As New Process
    dismC.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
    dismC.StartInfo.Arguments = " /Apply-Image /ImageFile:t:\" & imgFile & ".wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:c:\"
    dismC.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dismC.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dismC.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dismC.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dismC.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dismC.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dismC.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dismC.Start()
    dismC.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dismC.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dismC.Close()

    'Image D Drive
    Dim dismD As New Process
    dismD.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
    dismD.StartInfo.Arguments = " /Apply-Image /ImageFile:t:\" & imgFile & ".wim /index:2 /ApplyDir:d:\"
    dismD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dismD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dismD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dismD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dismD.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dismD.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dismD.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dismD.Start()
    dismD.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dismD.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dismD.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub reboot()
    'Reboots a pc while in WinPE
    Dim reset As New Process
    reset.StartInfo.FileName = "wpeutils.exe"
    reset.StartInfo.Arguments = " reboot"
    reset.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub WriteToLog(ByVal title As String, ByVal msg As String)
    'Check and make directory
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("t:\logs\") Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("t:\logs\")
    End If

    'Check and make file
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("t:\logs\" & pcSerial & ".log", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
    s.Close()
    fs.Close()

    'Logging
    Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream("t:\logs\" & pcSerial & ".log", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim s1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)
    s1.Write("Title: " & title & vbCrLf)
    s1.Write("Message: " & msg & vbCrLf)
    s1.Write("================================================" & vbCrLf)
    s1.Close()
    fs1.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Output(s As String)
    'Output to form window
    If s <> "" Then
        tb1.AppendText(vbCrLf & ">> " & s)
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Model()
    Get
        Model = pcModel
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetBiosSerialNumber() As String
    Dim OutputString As String = String.Empty
    Using Process As New Process
        AddHandler Process.OutputDataReceived,
    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        OutputString = OutputString & e.Data & vbCrLf
    End Sub
        With Process.StartInfo
            .FileName = "cmd"
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
        End With
        With Process
            .Start()
            .BeginOutputReadLine()
        End With
        Using InputStream As System.IO.StreamWriter = Process.StandardInput
            With InputStream
                .AutoFlush = True
                .Write("wmic bios get serialnumber" & vbCrLf)
            End With
        End Using
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until Process.HasExited
    End Using
    Return Replace(OutputString.Split(CChar(vbCrLf)).ToList(6).Substring(1), " ", "")
End Function

Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(text As String)
Public myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)
Public Sub UpdateTextBox(text As String)
    rtb1.Text += text & Environment.NewLine
    rtb1.SelectionStart = rtb1.Text.Length
    rtb1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Public Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
    Else
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: You're blocking your UI thread several times as you're spawning processes and then waiting for them. You should use separate threads to perform background work.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm still new to vb.net.  How do I make them separate threads?

Comment: And it's not really background work.  1 process needs to finish before the next is invoked.

Comment: From the UI perspective, anything that takes more than a few milliseconds is background work. If you block the UI from responding to user input for any percievable amount of time, the user will not be able to interact with the UI. You should look into using BackgroundWorker or tasks.

Comment: Backgroundworkers did it!  Thanks so much for the advice

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(text As String)
Public myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)

Private Property pcSerial As Object = GetBiosSerialNumber()
Private Property title As String = "Ross PC Imaging"
Private Property pcModel As Object
Private Property wkstn As String
Private Property srvr As Object
Private Property pctype As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call ross()
End Sub

Private Sub ross()
    Dim objCS As ManagementObjectSearcher
    Dim objMgmt As ManagementObject
    objCS = New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objMgmt In objCS.Get
        pcModel = objMgmt("model").ToString()
    Next

    Output(pcModel)
    Output(pcSerial)

    'Map network drive
    DriveMap.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub DriveMap_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles DriveMap.DoWork
    'Map network drive
    Dim map As New Process()
    map.StartInfo.FileName = "net.exe"
    map.StartInfo.Arguments = " use t: \\172.47.3.254\wims"
    map.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    map.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    map.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    map.Start()
    map.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub DriveMap_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles DriveMap.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - partitioning and formatting drives")
    Dim msgDiskPart As String : msgDiskPart = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - partitioning and formatting drives")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDiskPart)

    DiskPart.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub DiskPart_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles DiskPart.DoWork
    If pcModel = "Server" Then
        pctype = "srvr"
    Else
        pctype = "wkstn"
    End If

    'Diskpart disk partitioning
    Dim dp As New Process()
    dp.StartInfo.FileName = "diskpart.exe"
    dp.StartInfo.Arguments = " /s x:\" & pctype & "_diskpart.txt"
    dp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dp.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dp.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dp.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dp.Start()
    dp.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dp.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dp.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub DiskPart_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles DiskPart.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drives have been partitioned and formatted")
    Dim msgDiskPart As String : msgDiskPart = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drives have been partitioned and formatted")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDiskPart)
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - running disk check on drive C")
    Dim msgChkDskC As String : msgChkDskC = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - running disk check on drive C")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgChkDskC)

    ChkDskC.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDskC_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ChkDskC.DoWork
    Dim dc As New Process
    dc.StartInfo.FileName = "chkdsk.exe"
    dc.StartInfo.Arguments = " c: /f"
    dc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dc.Start()
    dc.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dc.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dc.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDskC_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles ChkDskC.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive C had no errors")
    Dim msgChkDskC As String : msgChkDskC = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive C had no errors")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgChkDskC)
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - running disk check on drive D")
    Dim msgChkDskD As String : msgChkDskD = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - running disk check on drive D")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgChkDskD)

    ChkDskD.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDskD_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles ChkDskD.DoWork
    Dim dc As New Process
    dc.StartInfo.FileName = "chkdsk.exe"
    dc.StartInfo.Arguments = " d: /f"
    dc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dc.Start()
    dc.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dc.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dc.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub ChkDskD_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles ChkDskD.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive D had no errors")
    Dim msgChkDskD As String : msgChkDskD = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive D had no errors")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgChkDskD)
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - imaging C drive")
    Dim msgDismC As String : msgDismC = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - imaging C drive")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDismC)

    DismC.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub DismC_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles DismC.DoWork
    If pcModel = "Server" Then
        pctype = "srvr"
    Else
        pctype = "wkstn"
    End If

    'Image C Drive
    Dim dismC As New Process
    dismC.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
    dismC.StartInfo.Arguments = " /Apply-Image /ImageFile:t:\" & pctype & ".wim /index:1 /ApplyDir:c:\"
    dismC.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dismC.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dismC.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dismC.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dismC.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dismC.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dismC.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dismC.Start()
    dismC.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dismC.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dismC.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub DismC_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles DismC.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive C imaged")
    Dim msgDismC As String : msgDismC = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive C imaged")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDismC)
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - imaging D drive")
    Dim msgDismD As String : msgDismD = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - imaging D drive")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDismD)

    DismD.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub DismD_DoWork(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles DismD.DoWork
    If pcModel = "Server" Then
        pctype = "srvr"
    Else
        pctype = "wkstn"
    End If

    'Image D Drive
    Dim dismD As New Process
    dismD.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe"
    dismD.StartInfo.Arguments = " /Apply-Image /ImageFile:t:\" & pctype & ".wim /index:2 /ApplyDir:d:\"
    dismD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    dismD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    dismD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    dismD.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    dismD.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    Application.DoEvents()
    AddHandler dismD.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    AddHandler dismD.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
    dismD.Start()
    dismD.BeginErrorReadLine()
    dismD.BeginOutputReadLine()
    dismD.WaitForExit()
End Sub

Private Sub DismD_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles DismD.RunWorkerCompleted
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive D imaged")
    Dim msgDismD As String : msgDismD = ("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - drive D imaged")
    Call WriteToLog(title, msgDismD)
    Output("[ " & Now & " ] PC - *" & pcSerial & "* - imaging complete, rebooting")

    'Call reboot()
End Sub

Private Sub reboot()
    'Reboots a pc while in WinPE
    Dim reset As New Process
    reset.StartInfo.FileName = "wpeutils.exe"
    reset.StartInfo.Arguments = " shutdown"
    reset.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub WriteToLog(ByVal title As String, ByVal msg As String)
    'Check and make directory
    If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("t:\logs\") Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("t:\logs\")
    End If

    'Check and make file
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream("t:\logs\" & pcSerial & ".log", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
    s.Close()
    fs.Close()

    'Logging
    Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream("t:\logs\" & pcSerial & ".log", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim s1 As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)
    s1.Write("Title: " & title & vbCrLf)
    s1.Write("Message: " & msg & vbCrLf)
    s1.Write("================================================" & vbCrLf)
    s1.Close()
    fs1.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Output(s As String)
    'Output to form window
    If s <> "" Then
        tb1.AppendText(vbCrLf & ">> " & s)
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property Model()
    Get
        Model = pcModel
    End Get
End Property

Public Function GetBiosSerialNumber() As String
    Dim OutputString As String = String.Empty
    Using Process As New Process
        AddHandler Process.OutputDataReceived,
    Sub(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        OutputString = OutputString & e.Data & vbCrLf
    End Sub
        With Process.StartInfo
            .FileName = "cmd"
            .UseShellExecute = False
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .RedirectStandardInput = True
            .RedirectStandardOutput = True
            .RedirectStandardError = True
        End With
        With Process
            .Start()
            .BeginOutputReadLine()
        End With
        Using InputStream As System.IO.StreamWriter = Process.StandardInput
            With InputStream
                .AutoFlush = True
                .Write("wmic bios get serialnumber" & vbCrLf)
            End With
        End Using
        Do
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop Until Process.HasExited
    End Using
    Return Replace(OutputString.Split(CChar(vbCrLf)).ToList(6).Substring(1), " ", "")
End Function

Public Sub UpdateTextBox(text As String)
    rtb1.Text += text & Environment.NewLine
    rtb1.SelectionStart = rtb1.Text.Length
    rtb1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub

Public Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
    Else
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class